# Emacs 24.3. highlight-regexp invisible match in current line due to hl-line-mode

Tags: emacs

Sometime I need to highlight a word in buffer, to do this I use  highlight-regexp command.
My problem is that match in current line is not visible because hl-line-mode override it, as in picture.

[image]

Is there a way to let highlight-regexp to take priority on hl-line-mode?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lock (of which `highlight-regexp` is a part) uses font-lock, which uses ***text properties***. Hl-line mode uses an ***overlay***. *Overlays always take priority over text properties.*

You can get what you want by using library **[`highlight.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/highlight.el)** instead, to highlight the regexp(s).  See ***[Highlight library](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/?action=browse;oldid=HighLight;id=HighlightLibrary)***. It is quite flexible, and lets you use overlays or text properties.

Comment: Thanks Drew. A little bit complicate but it works fine.

Comment: (1) I should also have mentioned that you can set the priority of an overlay, so it shows "on top of" other overlays that have a lower priority.  (2) Note that if you want behavior similar to hi-lock, in that it picks the face for you automatically, and *cycles to another face each time*, then customize option `hlt-auto-faces-flag` to non-`nil`.  (BTW, I just uploaded a new version that fixes a bug in this regard.)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use bold faces instead of «real» highlight. Use the faces that end with `-b`, like `hi-red-b`, instead of `hi-yellow`.

Comment: Thanks Ehvince. I have tried it and at last this can be my solution. But red bold foreground is not so evident as yellow (or other) background